# Terminology: induced graph and other related graphs

Tags: directed-graphs

I'm creating graph viewing utilities for real world use cases. My input is technically a directed acyclic graph with labelled edges and nodes.

As part of this I find myself generated graphs **related** to a graph in a number of different ways (subgraphs, edge-contraction).
 I am interested in using the correct terminology and common operations.

My question is twofold: **What operations to produce related graphs are common / have accepted terminology?** (i.e. like induced graphs, edge contraction)? (sorry this is a little vague but I'm looking for
 "where to start")

And is there a specific name for the follow graph operation (which I would be inclined to call a "reachability contraction over a subset of nodes."

$R(A, N) = G(N, \{(n, m): ( n, m \in N  ) \land  (\exists n_1...n_2)( P(n, n_1, n_2,..., n_i, m) \le A \land (\forall i)(n_i \notin N) \})$

Where

- $G(nodes, edges)$ is a graph of nodes and edges.
- $P(n_1,...n_i)$ is a path through nodes ($P(n_1,..., n_i) = G(\{n_1, ..., n_i\}, \{(n_a, n_{a+1}): 1 \le a \le i - 1 \})$)
- $G(A, B) \le G(C, D) \iff ( A \subseteq C ) \land  (B \subseteq D)$

Comment: I'm aware that this question might walk the line of being too general. If so, just, say and I shall take it to the appropriate subreddit instead.